# Хочу подключить к боту клавиатуру, но у меня вылезает ошибка, далее я напишу часть кода и ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Вот сама клавиатура:

```
# Клавиатура
keyboard = {
    "one_time": False,
    "buttons": [
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"1\"}",
                 "label": "1"
            },
            "color": "positive"
        }],
        [{
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"2\"}",
                "label": "2"
            },
            "color": "default"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "payload": "{\"button\": \"3\"}",
                "label": "3"
            },
            "color": "default"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Вот часть кода, где она подключается через `"keyboard": keyboard`:

```
elif message.upper() == self._ERR[0]:
                return f".", "keyboard": keyboard
```

Но у меня вылезает ошибка, которая указывает на `:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from vk_bot import VkBot
  File "C:\Users\V1zard\Desktop\dont_open\vkbot\vk_bot\vk_bot.py", line 79
    return f".", "keyboard": keyboard
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему, **очень срочно!**

Comment: Ошибка синтаксическая. Не понятно, чем Вам помочь, потому что Вы не сказали, что должен делать код, а конкретно — что должна вернуть функция.

Comment: "_Вот часть кода, где она [клавиатура] подключается_", — там ничего не подключается. Клавиатура (её класс) прикладывается к сообщению при отправке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return f".", "keyboard": keyboard` - пропущены фигурные скобки.

`return f".", {"keyboard": keyboard}`